# How can I accept credit cards with Square Reader SDK (in development) without SSN number?

Tags: square, square-reader

Square requires authorizing the location even if you need to test credit card payments with Reader SDK. That means, I need an SSN number, but I don't have an SSN since I'm a foreigner.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Square Reader SDK is only available in the United States, and not available in our sandbox. Therefore you do need to be based in the United States and have credit card processing enabled, even for testing (because you would be testing with your production credentials). Please refer to our docs for more information: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/readersdk/overview

Comment: Our company is a US based company. We have our EIN number, but founders don't have SSN. I think it should be possible to test it with that information.